# Custom LinkedList: Picking alternate integer elements

Tags: java, list, recursion

I have a list of `Integer` `[21, 9, 13, 47, 5, 10, 19, 36, 20, 11, 13]` and I'm trying to write a recursive function that will return every other integer from the original list as a list 
(i.e. `[21, 13, 5, 19, 20, 13]`).

I'm using a custom implementation of a LispList. The object is called **LispList** and it is *immutable* and (obviously) unindexed. It provides the following methods:

**E head()** - returns the first item of the list it is called on.
**LispList <E> tail()** - returns a new list consisting of all but the first item of the list it is called on.
**LispList <E> cons(E item)** - takes an argument and returns a new list whose head is the argument and whose tail is the list it is called on.
**boolean isEmpty()** - returns true if the list it is called on is the empty list, returns false otherwise.
**static <T> LispList<T> empty()** - returns an empty list.

After several hours of attempt, I've come up with a way where I'm using a counter initialised at 2 and using it to track even numbered elements, which should be picked out and put in a new LispList and returned.

However, when I run the code it throws a NullPointerException and I can't see why. Maybe I've just been staring at the screen for too long!

This is the method getting called from `main`:

```
public static <T> LispList<T> pickEveryOther(LispList<T> ls) {
        int counter = 2; 
        LispList<T> ls1 = pickEveryOtherHelper(ls.tail(), counter);
        return ls1;
}
```

and the helper method:

```
public static <T> LispList<T> pickEveryOtherHelper(LispList<T> ls, int counter) {
        LispList<T> wantLs = LispList.empty();
        if(ls.isEmpty()) {
            return LispList.empty();
        }
        else {
            if(counter % DIVIDER == 0) {
                // item we want
                wantLs = wantLs.cons(ls.head());
                counter++;
            }
            else {
                // don't want item, look in tail
                pickEveryOtherHelper(ls.tail(), counter);
            }
            return wantLs;
        }
    }
```

Greatly appreciate your efforts.

Comment: `DIVIDER=2` by the way (inside method pickEveryOtherHelper). It's a global, sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pop 2 values off the list on each recursion, and build a new list using one of the 2 values.

You didn't really specify whether "every other" means 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... or 2nd, 4th, 6th, ..., so here is both solutions.

```java
public static <T> LispList<T> pickOdd(LispList<T> ls) {
    if (ls.isEmpty())
        return ls; // return empty
    LispList<T> tail1 = ls.tail();
    if (tail1.isEmpty())
        return ls; // return of(ls.head())
    LispList<T> tail2 = tail1.tail();
    if (tail2.isEmpty())
        return tail2.cons(ls.head()); // return of(ls.head())
    return pickOdd(tail2).cons(ls.head());
}
```

```java
public static <T> LispList<T> pickEven(LispList<T> ls) {
    if (ls.isEmpty())
        return ls; // return empty
    LispList<T> tail1 = ls.tail();
    if (tail1.isEmpty())
        return tail1; // return empty
    LispList<T> tail2 = tail1.tail();
    if (tail2.isEmpty())
        return tail1; // return of(ls.tail().head())
    return pickEven(tail2).cons(tail1.head());
}
```

To test it, I did implement `LispList`, with two helper methods (`of(...)` and `toString()`):

```java
final class LispList<E> {
    private final E           head;
    private final LispList<E> tail;
    private LispList(E head, LispList<E> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    /** returns the first item of the list it is called on */
    public E head() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return this.head;
    }
    /** returns a new list consisting of all but the first item of the list it is called on */
    public LispList<E> tail() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return this.tail;
    }
    /** takes an argument and returns a new list whose head is the argument and whose tail is the list it is called on */
    public LispList<E> cons(E item) {
        return new LispList<>(item, this);
    }
    /** returns true if the list it is called on is the empty list, returns false otherwise */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.tail == null;
    }
    /** returns an empty list */
    public static <T> LispList<T> empty() {
        return new LispList<>(null, null);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> LispList<T> of(T ... values) {
        LispList<T> ls = empty();
        for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            ls = ls.cons(values[i]);
        return ls;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
        for (LispList<E> ls = this; ! ls.isEmpty(); ls = ls.tail())
            joiner.add(String.valueOf(ls.head()));
        return joiner.toString();
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```java
LispList<Integer> ls = LispList.of(21, 9, 13, 47, 5, 10, 19, 36, 20, 11, 13);
System.out.println("List: " + ls);
System.out.println("Odd : " + pickOdd(ls));
System.out.println("Even: " + pickEven(ls));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
List: [21, 9, 13, 47, 5, 10, 19, 36, 20, 11, 13]
Odd : [21, 13, 5, 19, 20, 13]
Even: [9, 47, 10, 36, 11]
```

Comment: I wanted the odd values hence "(i.e. [21, 13, 5, 19, 20, 13])". +1 for the very neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, just take the head of, then try to take the tail two times and recurse on that. Just account for the fact that it can become an empty list after every tail. And then prepend the head to the result of the recursion.

```
public static <T> LispList<T> everyOther(LispList<T> lispList) {
    if (lispList.isEmpty()) {
        return lispList.empty();
    }
    T head = lispList.head();
    LispList<T> tail = lispList.tail();
    if (!tail.isEmpty()) {
        tail = tail.tail();
    }
    tail = everyOther(tail);
    return tail.cons(head);
}
```

Comment: Was about to say it would crash on empty list, but you fixed it. :-) Should just do `return lispList`, though, and no need for `else` following an `return`. Keep things unindented.

Comment: I included the empty so that it would be more in style with the rest of the code in the way that it returns an edited copy of the list and never the list itself. So that you can get a result and work on that without changing the original. You're right about the else though. I edited that out.

Comment: "'without changing the original" is an unnecessary consideration given that "LispList [...] is *immutable*". So, for an empty list or a list of only one element, you can return the list itself. [My code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36813698/5221149) is slightly longer, in order to implement that optimization. Either way is good and gives the desired result.

Comment: When I run it with my client, it's still throwing a NullPointer on the line where you call `head()` on `lisplist`.

Comment: @orion_IX If `head()` throws NPE after `isEmpty()` returned false, then your `LispList` is flawed. See working implementation in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36813698/5221149), which does work with solution in this answer.

Comment: Oh, @DaanvanderKallen, `empty()` is static, so `lispList.empty()` should be `LispList.empty()` (class call, not instance call).

Comment: @Andreas my bad, I was using the old code that was posted (page wasn't refreshed of changes). The NPE is gone, but when I try to print the returned LispList for this function it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @orion_IX It's easier to both test and debug if you implement `toString()`, like I did. I tried this solution with my implementation of `LispList`, and it works fine.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, noted for the future. Recursion has never been by forte to be honest. I'm studying your solution to see how it works. Cheers again.

Comment: @DaanvanderKallen It turns out there was a bug in my client that was causing an empty list to be returned by your function. Your code is all good, I've tested it. Thanks.